# How can I automatically import emails that are exactly the same in content/layout with different data points into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-parsing

I receive emails that have the same layout and data type. I want to automatically have that data imported into a specific Google Sheet.

I use Office 365 and Outlook 365.
The emails all come from the same email address.

The content of the email is a Bolded Name at the top and 5 lines of data. Nothing else.

Example:

```
**Name Name Name** (NEEDED DATA)
useless line of text
data: (NEEDED DATA)
data: (NEEDED DATA)
data: (NEEDED DATA)
data: (NEEDED DATA)
data: (NEEDED DATA)
```

The script, addon or program would then take this data from the email and then put it into a specific Google Sheet. Each line of data inserted into a column (1-6) for data lines (1-6) on the next available row within the Google Sheet.

My thoughts on how this could be done:

- (BEST OPTION for me) Outlook script/addon
- (Best Option for me) Pre-existing program/service/addon
- gMail Addon script
- PHP script housed on a server that receives the email address

What I have done so far:

- I have researched online looking for prebuilt software or code. (I'm perfectly ok with using anything like this)
- I have searched addons for outlook.

Comment: If it's that structured it should be easy for you to come up with something on your own.  Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

You could split on line feeds.  Then splice out the second line. And then

`line.slice(line.indexOf('(')+1,line.indexof(')');`  or you could use regular expressions.

You could do all of this in a gmail addon.